# Trying to get the sum in Ruby - NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an items table and I am trying to get the total amount of purchases using the `.sum` method in Ruby. I am not sure why it's not working.

Model.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def profit_calc
    sold_for - bought_for - fees - shipping
  end

  def purchase_total
    items.sum(&:bought_for)
  end

  scope :visible, -> { where(sold: false) }
  scope :sold, -> { where(sold: true) }
end
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "description"
  t.float    "bought_for"
  t.float    "sold_for"
  t.float    "fees"
  t.float    "shipping"
  t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  t.boolean  "sold",                default: false
end
```

Items Controller:

```
def statistics
  @items = Item.all
  @items_day = Item.all.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
  @items_week = Item.all.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week, Time.zone.now.end_of_week)
  @items_month = Item.all.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, Time.zone.now.end_of_month)
end
```

Statistics.html.erb:

```
<h1 id="title">Statistics</h1>
<br>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Today</th>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Total Purchases</th>
      <th>Total Fees</th>
      <th>Total Shipping</th>
      <th>Total Sales</th>
      <th>Total Profit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_with_delimiter(@items.count) %></td>
      <td><%= @items_day.count %></td>
      <td><%= @items_week.count %></td>
      <td><%= @items_month.count %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(item.purchase_total) %></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: First do `items = Item.all` in `purchase_total` method before calling `items.sum...`

Comment: also (out of the scope of the question), you can move those calculations (day, week, month) into Item scopes, like: `scope :daily -> { where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day) }` and ask for them in the controller: `@daily_count = Item.daily.count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need class method in the model:

```
def self.purchase_total
  to_a.sum(&:bought_for)
end
```

Or do calculation in the SQL (which is much performant):

```
def self.purchase_total
  sum(:bought_for)
end
```

And call this method on relation in the view:

```
<td><%= number_to_currency(@items.purchase_total) %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**One simple way but not optimized:** 

 def purchase_total
    items.sum(&:bought_for)
 end

replace with

 def purchase_total(items)
    items.sum(&:bought_for)
 end

And Update call

item.purchase_total(@items)


**Another way:**

In Controller

@items = Item.all
@purchase_total = @items.sum(&:bought_for)

And in erb
<td><%= number_to_currency(item.purchase_total) %></td>

replace with

<td><%= number_to_currency(@purchase_total) %></td>
```